# How do you pass a MaterialPageRoute to a Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am trying to make a widget which has a gesture detector and will open a MaterialPageRoute when you press on it. In the build method, I want to enter 3 constructors, a label, an icon, and finally the route. The label and icon both work fine. I'm not sure what kind of variable to use or the syntax for the link though. I am still pretty new to Flutter and programming in general.

When pressed, the "ToolMaker" in this code should navigate to the MaterialPageRoute that I specify, which in this case is ScoreKeeper(). The below code gives me an error of "The argument type 'ScoreKeeper' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Navigator'"

'''

```
class ToolsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('Tools'),
        Row(
          children: [
            ToolMaker('Score Board', Icon(Icons.score_outlined), ScoreKeeper()),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ToolMaker extends StatelessWidget {
  @required
  final String label;
  @required
  final Icon icon;
  final Navigator link;

  const ToolMaker(this.label, this.icon, this.link);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => this.link,
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: this.icon,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(this.label)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

> When pressed, the "ToolMaker" in this code should navigate to the MaterialPageRoute

this is a function,you have several options

**1)** Use a function parameter instead of `final Navigator link;` use `final Function onTap;`

in your gesture detector onTap call the oncall func

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap:widget.onTap,
```

then when creating your widget parse the parameter

```
 ToolMaker('Score Board', Icon(Icons.score_outlined),myFunction),
```

**tip** use named arguments by adding {} around your widget constructors

```
 const ToolMaker({this.label, this.icon, this.link});
```

**2**
navigate using

[named routes.](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the type `Navigator` to `Widget`.